# Adding foreign key constraint results in Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row during

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

The following error  occurs when I am trying to add a foreign key constraint to one of my tables running the following command:

```
alter table `word_lists` add constraint `word_lists_image_id_foreign` foreign key (`image_id`) references `images` (`id`) on delete set null;
```

The complete error message:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`palabi_54`.`#sql-3a2_395`, CONSTRAINT `word_lists_image_id_foreign`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`image_id`) REFERENCES `images` (`id`) ON DELETE SET
>   NULL) (SQL:      alter table `word_lists` add constraint
>   `word_lists_image_id_foreign` foreign key (`image_id`) references
>   `images` (`id`) on delete set null)

This is my word_lists table:
[image: word_lists table]

And this is my images table:
[image: images table]

Comment: Sounds like you have an image_id in word_lists that doesn't exist in images.

Comment: But as you can see, there is a image_id column in wors_lists-table and a id column in my images-table . Nothing missing there

Comment: I was not suggesting that the column doesn't exist.  I was suggesting that a value doesn't match.  In  essence, your solution described exactly what I suggested.  0 did not exist in the images table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the solution by myself:

The word_lists table already had records stored in it. These records had 0 instead of NULL as value for image_id. Also I had to set the default value for image_id in word_lists to NULL. And this field has to be nullable.